# Web scraping with VBA vs Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to automate web scraping by Excel. It's just accessing the website and download the data as an excel file.
I have three options; any recommendation or suggestions?

1. Use VBA and manipulate browser
2. Use VBA and http requests.
3. Call Python script from VBA

I prefer Python so much. However,I need to make it environment-independent and useable for anyone else who's not familiar with codes at all, so I would like to avoid extra installation and setup.

Any advise will help. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I've scraped with both those technologies but I prefer a third technology and that's a Chrome Extension which are written in JavaScript.  What is special about a Chrome Extension is that is is embedded in the browser and you can then pass the data along to some VBA code.  Here is a full demo, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDf3dsua9qk

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go with whatever you feel the most comfortable with.

What I personally do when I need to distribute my Python applications is to create a standalone using [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). You should be able to create standalones for several environments.

Comment: Thank you, I am taking a look at Pyinstaller now.